# How can run-time errors be distinguished from others?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, errors

Consider the following error message.

> Msg 207 Level 16 State 1 Line 7
>
> Invalid column name 'FOO'.

Because of [how I trigged it](https://dbfiddle.uk/g1xFlpDZ), I happen to know that is was a parse/compile time error.

Suppose that I was running a long script that was not part of a procedure and I got this same error message. What in this error message tells me that the error was at parse/compile time rather than run time?

---

```
CREATE TABLE Department_History
(
    DepartmentNumber INT
);
GO

ALTER TABLE Department_History ADD FOO INT;

-- This is fine and shows FOO.
SELECT * FROM Department_History;

-- When uncommented, this fails at parse time.
INSERT Department_History (DepartmentNumber, FOO) VALUES (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9);
```

Comment: I didnt get any error message.It work for me and last insert was succesful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is not happening at parse time. It will succeed if you run Parse (Ctrl + F5) over your code selection.

Instead, the problem is in the Bind step.

I'll borrow this graph from Paul White's blog post [Query Optimizer Deep Dive - Part 1](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/04/query-optimizer-deep-dive-part-1.html)

[image]

As for the question, I don't believe the SQL server (easily) surfaces in which step the error happened.

I've captured the error's call stack with Extended Events and then used [SQLCallStackResolver](https://github.com/microsoft/SQLCallStackResolver) to translate that

```
value   count
00 sqllang!XeSqlPkg::error_reported::Publish
01 sqllang!ErrorReportedAutoPublish::Publish
02 sqllang!CErrorReportingManager::CwchFormatAndPrint
03 sqllang!ex_vcallprint_no_dump
04 sqllang!SQLCompileHandler
05 SqlDK!CallExceptionHandler
06 SqlDK!ex_raise2
07 SqlDK!ex_raise_va_list
08 sqllang!alg_ex_raise
09 sqllang!CScaOp_Identifier::BindSelf
0a sqllang!CScaOpArg::BindScalarTree
0b sqllang!CScaOpArg::BindTree
0c sqllang!COptExpr::BindTree
0d sqllang!CRelOp_DML::BindColumnList
0e sqllang!CRelOp_Insert::GetLhsTypesForUnion
0f sqllang!CRelOp_Insert::BindTree
10 sqllang!COptExpr::BindTree
11 sqllang!CRelOp_DMLQuery::BindTree
12 sqllang!COptExpr::BindTree
13 sqllang!CRelOp_Query::FAlgebrizeQuery
14 sqllang!CProchdr::FNormQuery
15 sqllang!CProchdr::FNormalizeStep
16 sqllang!CSQLSource::FCompile
17 sqllang!CSQLSource::FCompWrapper
18 sqllang!CSQLSource::Transform
19 sqllang!CSQLSource::Compile
1a sqllang!CStmtPrepQuery::Init
1b sqllang!CCompPlan::FCompileStep
1c sqllang!CSQLSource::FCompile
```

You can see that just before the exception, it tried to `BindTree`.

Comment: Very helpful! Also, you might want to comment the call stack that you've given. The untrained eye has no idea what line(s) to look at or how/where they match the picture you've included.